# Perform a single function on multiple object

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to perform a single function on multiple objects by e.g. grouping them. What I want to do is something like:

```
{object1, object2, object3}.toFront();
```

Comment: How do select the various `node.rectangle` elements/objects?

Comment: The various elements of rectangle are not relevant for the question, I just want to combine the objects. Updated question, see above.

Comment: It's very relevant, since the `Array` or `Object` prototypes can be extended to perform defined functions on arrays or a node List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you've already accepted an answer, this is possible in a similar manner either natively through JavaScript 1.6/ECMAScript 5<sup>th</sup> Edition:

```
function logElementID(element, index, array) {
    var el = array[index],
        prop = el.textContent ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
    el[prop] = el.id;
}

[document.getElementById('one'), document.getElementById('two')].forEach(logElementID);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eAGeX/).

Or by extending the `Object` prototype:

```
function doStuff (el) {
    console.log(el);
};

Object.prototype.actOnGroup = function(func){
    var els = this.length ? this : [this];
    for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i<len; i++){
        func(els[i]);
    }
    return this;
};

document.getElementsByTagName('div').actOnGroup(doStuff);
document.getElementById('one').actOnGroup(doStuff);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eAGeX/3/).

Or by, similarly, extending the `Array` prototype:

```
function doStuff (el) {
    console.log(el);
};
Array.prototype.actOnGroup = function(func){
    var els = this.length ? this : [this];
    for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i<len; i++){
        func(els[i]);
    }
    return this;
};

[document.getElementById('one'), document.getElementById('two')].actOnGroup(doStuff);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eAGeX/4/).

Incidentally, if you'd like to provide a `forEach()` alternative to users without (relatively) up-to-date JavaScript implementations, the Mozilla Developer Network page for `forEach()` offers the following as '[an] algorithm 100% true to the ECMA-262, 5th edition':

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.18
// Reference: http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.18
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {

    Array.prototype.forEach = function forEach(callback, thisArg) {

        var T, k;

        if (this == null) {
            throw new TypeError("this is null or not defined");
        }

        // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| value as the argument.
        var O = Object(this);

        // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with the argument "length".
        // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
        var len = O.length >>> 0; // Hack to convert O.length to a UInt32

        // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
        // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
        if ({}.toString.call(callback) !== "[object Function]") {
            throw new TypeError(callback + " is not a function");
        }

        // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
        if (thisArg) {
            T = thisArg;
        }

        // 6. Let k be 0
        k = 0;

        // 7. Repeat, while k < len
        while (k < len) {

            var kValue;

            // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
            //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
            // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal method of O with argument Pk.
            //   This step can be combined with c
            // c. If kPresent is true, then
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(O, k)) {

                // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with argument Pk.
                kValue = O[k];

                // ii. Call the Call internal method of callback with T as the this value and
                // argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
                callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
            }
            // d. Increase k by 1.
            k++;
        }
        // 8. return undefined
    };
}
```

Copied verbatim, from the reference (below) from the MDN `forEach()` article; 01/04/2013, at 14:30.

References:

- [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Wow, really useful overview. Thanks for that!

Comment: I fail to see why would anyone want to define an `actOnGroup` function, which is almost identical to `each`/`forEach` (with the only difference that it's less useful since it does not return the original array), except to make for a really long answer.

Comment: It's on option is all, I prefer the alternative implementation of `forEach`, personally, I simply chose to expand the answer by showing how one can, if desired, extend the prototype of an `Object` or `Array`. Though admittedly I would, normally, return the original object (I'll edit that in, momentarily).

Answer (score 2):

A simple way:

```
var nodes = [node.rectangle1, node.text, node.rectangle2];
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].toFront();
}
```

If you use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke) and like brevity:

```
_.invoke([node.rectangle1, node.text, node.rectangle2], 'toFront');
```

If you want the return values you can use [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) or if you just want some extra processing look at [each](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

EDIT (to make this complete):

You can also use the built-in `forEach` (if you don't care about some browsers or you choose to shim it) in a very similar fashion to the underscore `each`:

```
[node.rectangle1, node.text, node.rectangle2].forEach(function(el) {
    el.toFront();
});
```

Comment: if you can use underscore , you could probably use the _.map()

Comment: @user1537158 I already mentioned map and each, but didn't provide an example as there's one already given directly in the docs and `invoke` seems what he's really after in this case.